# How to add text field with button when click on Add(+) button, again click new added button add one more fields in android?

Tags: android, button, layout

i am suffering from last one week with this problem. I have one  row with EditText text field, setTime button, and Addmore button. Now when i click setTime button open dialod and set time, it will displayed in text field. After this click on Addmore button then create new row same like above and when click setTime button again add time into text  field. Now click on Addmore button it will create another row like above with same functionality. I did when click on setTime button it will add to text Field. now i want to click Addmore button it will create new row like above with same fuctionality with the  set time and add more button. 
I did set time code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener 
{
     Button SetTime,addFields;
     EditText  timeTxt;
     SetTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SetTime);
     SetTime.setOnClickListener(this);

           if (v == SetTime) {

            // Process to get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMin = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                int minute) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            timeTxt.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMin, false);
            tpd.show();
        }

}
```

XML File

```
 <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <EditText 
      android:layout_width="240dp"
      android:layout_height="65sp"
      android:id="@+id/txtTime"
      android:textSize="27sp">

        <requestFocus>
       </requestFocus>

    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SetTime"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25sp"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="65sp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="SetTime" >
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddTimings"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"            
        android:layout_width="140sp"
        android:layout_height="65sp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="ADD(+)" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Create a layout of any name for example child layout
and create your main XML file in which you will include child layout and then when add more button is pressed then add the child of the main layout

Comment: can u provide any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found very good example...this resolved my problem

```
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/05/add-and-remove-view-dynamically.html
```

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Seems to be available now.

Answer (score 0):

You have add like the following code,

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("New");    
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```

Comment: hi gunaseelan, can u provide an example for this task. I have confusion to understand this task. Actually i have one edit text, two buttons in a row, when click last button add new new row with same as above means with one text field, two button, again when click last button in a row, again create a new row with these widgets.